# How can I get the taxonomy term name from a term ID?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to get a taxonomy term name by term ID. According to another post, I should load the term first:

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy')->load($tid);
```

But then I get this error :

> Notice: Undefined property: Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference::$target

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the term name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 $term_name = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($term_id)->get('name')->value;
```

You will get the Term Name

Comment: Slight change but you can use `label()` instead of `get('name')->value`. With all entities, usually, by the way, so you don't need to know whether it's _name_ or anything else.

Answer (score 40):

Or you can simply use The entity Term class:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
```

and in your code:

```
$term = Term::load($tid);
$name = $term->getName();
```

Comment: My first instinct upon looking at this was "oh no, what about the dependency injection they keep hitting us over the head with in Drupal-land thesedays?", but - on inspection - the static ::load($id) method shared by all types of entities has all of the necessary dependency injection support built in - so this would now be my pick of how to load an entity of any kind (node, comment etc). In fact it beats me why anyone would use the long-hand \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->blah->blah->blah method now! (maybe someone else will chime in and give a good reason for that?)

Comment: @DanielScott – `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('ENTITY_TYPE_ID')->load($id);` is very easy to remember. You simply replace `ENTITY_TYPE_ID` and then you can `load` or `loadMultiple` or `loadByProperties` etc. And it works for nodes, for terms, for users, for roles, for vocabularies, for node types etc. You can even query the database from it.

Comment: @DanielScott, not the question or both answers are about dependency injection. This would look like `$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('ENTITY_TYPE_ID')->load($id);`. But the long-hand static call makes refactoring easier if you need DI.

Answer (score 19):

The correct code is the following one.

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);
```

The entity type is *taxonomy_term*, not *taxonomy*.

Then, use `$term->getName()`.