# Taxonomy term name issue

Tags: taxonomy-terms

```
$tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('category');
var_dump(tree);
```

the above snippet gives the following output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[389]
      public 'tid' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'vid' => string 'category' (length=8)
      public 'langcode' => string 'en' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'General' (length=7)
      public 'description__value' => null
      public 'description__format' => null
      public 'weight' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'changed' => string '1501133997' (length=10)
      public 'default_langcode' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'depth' => int 0
      public 'parents' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[393]
      public 'tid' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'vid' => string 'category' (length=8)
      public 'langcode' => string 'en' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'OBC' (length=3)
      public 'description__value' => null
      public 'description__format' => null
      public 'weight' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'changed' => string '1501134006' (length=10)
      public 'default_langcode' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'depth' => int 0
      public 'parents' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '0' (length=1)
 .....
```

My question is how can i get the name i.e.,general,obc etc (i mean taxonomy term name) from the above snippet...i am new to drupal..plz help..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
  $tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('category');

  foreach ($tree as $key => $term) {
    $term_name = $term->name;
    var_dump($term_name);
  }
```

View this [topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233522/how-to-get-term-name-from-a-tid).

Comment: this gives me only one last term of vocabulary whereas i want all the terms of vocabulary..plz help...

Comment: $tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('category');
   
    $categories=array();
    $categories_arr = array();
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tree);$i++){
      
   //  array_push($categories, $term->getName(($tree[$i]->tid)));
     $pracice_name=taxonomy_term_load($tree[$i]->tid)->get('name')->value;
     array_push($categories_arr,$pracice_name);
    }

Comment: this solved my problem.